# Transition the height of a div to fit its contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` that is used to display any info message to the user.

[image]

Initial `height` of this div is `zero` and `display` is `none`. When there's any message to display to the user, i display it using `javascript`.

I transition the height of this `div` from `0` to `48px` which gives the effect of this `div` sliding down slowly.

**problem**

As the `height` of this is set to `48px`, if message inside is long, it doesn't increases it's height to prevent the overflow of text.

Message displayed in full size browser window

[image]

Same message displayed in small browser window

[image]

**question**

How can i set the height of this div in javascript so that its height adjusts to fit its contents.

**HTML**

```
<!--used for displaying error or success message-->
<p id="info-message-block">
   <span></span>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.error-msg-block,
.success-msg-block {
  display: none;
  background: #dc3545;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
  transition: height 0.6s ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 85%;
}

.error-msg-block span,
.success-msg-block span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px 0 0 20px;
}
```

**javascript function to display this info message**

```
let displayInfoMessage = function (message, messageType) {
    'use strict';
    let messageBlock = document.querySelector('#info-message-block');
    messageBlock.style.display = 'block';
    messageBlock.firstElementChild.textContent = message;

    if (messageType === 'error') {
        messageBlock.className = 'error-msg-block';
    } else {
        messageBlock.className = 'success-msg-block';
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        messageBlock.style.height = '48px';
    }, 10);
};
```

Comment: why you don't simplify and you use max-height instead ? you make 0 and you increase to a big value

Comment: @TemaniAfif because there are other elements below this `div`, if i increase to big value, it will slide other elements down

Comment: no, it's wrong ;) max-height will define max, it won't make the height bigger ... try it an see, keep the height:auto, then adjust max-height from 0 to a big value

Comment: It might be silly, but you could create that div, set only its width so the height of the div will get set automatically, get its height while it is still invisible, then you can transition it from 0 to that height. Getting div while its display is set to none might be tricky, but there are solutions, just google it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif i have included couple of images that might help you understand my problem

Comment: I got it :) and am convinced my solution will work ;) give it a try I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above here is the idea using `max-height` instead of `height`

```js
let displayInfoMessage = function(message, messageType) {
  'use strict';
  let messageBlock = document.querySelector('#info-message-block');
  messageBlock.style.display = 'block';
  messageBlock.firstElementChild.textContent = message;

  if (messageType === 'error') {
    messageBlock.className = 'error-msg-block';
  } else {
    messageBlock.className = 'success-msg-block';
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    messageBlock.style.maxHeight = '120px'; /*Make this value big enough to cover the worst case*/
  }, 10);
};

displayInfoMessage("this is a very loooong loooong loooong loooong message for test")
```

```css
body {
 max-width:200px;
}

.error-msg-block,
.success-msg-block {
  display: none;
  background: #dc3545;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  max-height: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 85%;
}

.error-msg-block span,
.success-msg-block span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 20px;
}
```

```html
<p id="info-message-block">
  <span></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply say `messageBlock.style.height = 'auto'` instead of setting a fixed value.

If the auto height is wrong, adjust it using padding.

If you want to limit the possible height, set `max-height` in the stylesheet.

Adding this answer as it seems like possibility of using `auto` is the real missing piece here, and using `max-height` is just working this lack of knowledge around.